# Change the menu color at one point of one page site

Tags: jquery, css, menu, colors, web

I am making a one page portfolio. The content of the site will be horizontal scrollable, only the menu is fixed. The first 2 pages are black and last one is white. But the 3rd page is half black and half white, it's kind a seperator of the two backgrounds.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiVqu.jpg]

This is so far the best solution for my question: http://jsfiddle.net/a5a7x/1/
I only have problems to make it horizotnal not vertical.

This is the page content where i want to put the split: http://jsfiddle.net/n3FGr/

Remember, i only need to split the menu, because it will be fixed, so only the menu will have the split, when the content wil slide left and right.

Comment: Is background image or color?

Comment: Should'nt be a problem changing the text color depending on how much is scrolled etc. but changing the color of the text right in the middle of a letter like that is'nt possible unless you're menu is a canvas and you you use a bunch of complicated trickery.

Comment: @adeneo no, it can be achieved with css gradients/background fun, actually there is no need in canvas

Comment: the background is currently color (css), but there is no problem to do it with images.

Comment: @madfriend - Well, the background is pretty much set, it's the scrollable black and white. Please feel free to show us how it can be done with gradients, and not some semi transparent letters changing colors etc. it has to be black and white ?

Comment: @user1544266 - any chance you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example with just the scrollable background and the menu, so we something to play with.

Comment: wow you guys are quick.

So here is the site i created: http://dejan-markovic.com/DM-test/

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7YXC/

And here is the site i found, that use the same thing i want to. And the menu it's made with images and z-index: http://www.tokiolab.it/#/

Comment: Hack: http://jsfiddle.net/KGWwD/. Wondering if there's a nice way.

Comment: the jsfiddle whas wrong, here is the right one: http://jsfiddle.net/V7YXC/1/

Comment: @pimvdb thank you! Now it's just one thing, on the right side is the menu, but on the right site i want to put the logo in. So a image, that should do the same thing like the menu. It's this possible?

Comment: @pimvdb - That's pretty cool using nth-of-type, now to make it work for scrolling and diagonal seperator ?

Comment: @adeneo for the diagonal you just made the background color with css, like i do it on my site..  I also whas wondering, could it be done with jquery like the before/after plugin? link: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

Comment: @user1544266 - Ah, I see, but as far as I know nth-of-type does'nt work that way, the changes are on the element, does'nt matter what you're background is, even if you set it to transparent instead of white it won't show properly, look here - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KGWwD/2/) ...

Comment: what if the menu is a image? And the change happens with the z-index. The only problem is, that the menu is fixed, so all changes can only be made with scrollable background. It can be made so, that the menu is scrollable like the content, so that at the end i have 4 differend menus. But i better prefer the complicated menu, it would be more awesome.

Comment: or what if i make the background with two layers - the black and the white. And when the 3rd page comes in, the white menu goes under the white background.. But i can't figure it out how than a black menu should come out from under another layer, maybe a unvisable one..

Comment: With the diagonal, I wasn't able to get it working through CSS, only through SVG: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5RCg/1/.

Comment: @pimvdb i [got it with pure css](http://dabblet.com/gist/3181530) (just toggle all four percents) but with pure browser support. my detail [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11668250/1057730)

Answer (score 6):

### Quick&Dirty rather close solution

[image: gradient on text]

I have explored the way to achieve your goal and have the some experiments:

- [Text in middle-center](http://dabblet.com/gist/3181406)
- [Text in left-top angle](http://dabblet.com/gist/3181519)
- [Menu in left-top angle](http://dabblet.com/gist/3181530)
  [image]

I have not full solution, but the result is pretty good: ([**demo on dabblet**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3181406))

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h1>Chess</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 52%, white 52%);
}

ul {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 52%, black 52%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

#### Method of work:

Sync percents in each gradients:

**52%:** [image]
**62%:** [image]

**Pros:**

- Plain html&css;

**Cons:**

- Only webkit support;

### The *Canvas*-way

**Pros:**

- Cross-browser (mobile too)

**Cons:**

- Javascript needed

### The *SVG*-way

**Pros:**

- Cross-browser
- Javascript free (in static)
- More semantical then Canvas

Comment: Thanks. Your idea inspired me - here's the result of my fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/teHLS/.

Comment: i want to try it in the SVG way.. this solutions are really great, but i just have always problems, when it comes to horrizontal scrolling of the page.. With your code you tell the elements what is behind on that angled-split page. But i have first some black pages, and than comes the half page.. Im trying now some how to make SVG text, but to put on background inverted image of all pages.. so on black is white text and then on white is black text.. but it's no simpl..

Comment: @DeanDeey Yes, it rather diffucult problem. What have you done?

Comment: jup, that's the problem. Many solutions, but when it comes to moving things etc. scrolling, then i always have problems. I try it with SVG text clipping. So make the menu from SVG, and then put behind an invertet black/white image, which should scroll with the content, so the text should perfectly change.. but it whas just theory.. and the bigest problem whas, that the code for SVG should be together, etc 10 lines, but i needed to put the clipping image on the content div, and there i stopped.

Comment: The last thing i come up with is this: http://jsfiddle.net/a5a7x/1/  i think it could actually work, because it is scrollable, because my prepared site is also, just the scroll is not visible because of the css: overflow: hidden. But i got problems to get this thing to horizontal scroll.

Comment: Your solution is the best, only if you not pay attentionn to content duplication. I will try create SVG solution tomorrow (now 6 a.m. in my area)

Comment: yea.. but i need this split angle just for the menu. So only menu will be duplicated and nothign else. So i don't mind it. Also the the menu will be cca 80px big, and only there i want the split to happen. :) and  that's it.
Oh, i will be really greatfull if u could help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do a diagonal gradient in css3 with say black for 50% and then white at 51%?

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left top, rgb(0,0,0) 54%, rgb(255,255,255) 55%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(0,0,0) 54%, rgb(255,255,255) 55%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(0,0,0) 54%, rgb(255,255,255) 55%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(0,0,0) 54%, rgb(255,255,255) 55%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(0,0,0) 54%, rgb(255,255,255) 55%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
right bottom,
color-stop(0.54, rgb(0,0,0)),
color-stop(0.55, rgb(255,255,255))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing CSS color onclick of the menu item:

```
$('#link1 a').click(function(){
    goTo(0,0);
$('#navigation ul li a').css('color','#fff');  
});


$('#link2 a').click(function(){
    goTo(1,0);
$('#navigation ul li a').css('color','#fff');
});

$('#link3 a').click(function(){
    goTo(2,0);
$('#navigation ul li a').css('color','#000');
});

$('#link4 a').click(function(){
    goTo(3,0);
$('#navigation ul li a').css('color','#000');
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/V7YXC/2/

Comment: script makes menu black on black page, and only after that scrolling to white page